# how to set default time in extjs datefield when date format is 'd-M-Y H:i:s'

Tags: extjs

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        format: 'd-M-Y H:i:s',
        name: 'from_date',
        value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1)
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'To',
        name: 'to_date',
        format: 'd-M-Y H:i:s',
        value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1)  // defaults to yesterday even i want to set default time
    }]
});
```

Comment: i want to set default time with default date when datefield format is 'd-M-Y H:i:s'

Comment: now i am getting default date with current time how to get default time also

Answer (score 0):

You can show only time from the given date y this code:

```
format: 'h:i:s',
value: Ext.Date.format((Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1)), h:i:s')
```

Check this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2743)

Hope this helps.

Comment: when datefield format is 'd-M-Y H:i:s' i am getting as "22-sept-2017 19:25:41"  i can set default date value to the datefield but how to set default value to time currently i am getting default date value with current time

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2743)